# How can I install a Flutter app on iPhone in Windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, flutter, installation

I have developed an app with Flutter in Windows 10 and I have my iPhone 6S. I have tried to install it through iTunes, but I can't. How can I install the app on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an iOS App without a macOS machine. That is not a limitation of Flutter, but rather a problem all app developers face. No matter what technology or toolkit you use, you can only create the app on an Apple device.

Some have made a business out of that and offer you an Apple device as a service or for rent, some developers just buy the cheapest used Mac they can get away with. But you need a Mac. Sorry.

The guide on how to deploy your app when you have a Mac can be found [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios).

Comment: Thank you. I will buy a cheap mac mini

Comment: Actually, this is possible with Xamarin development.  You can create an iOS app on Windows by connecting your iPhone through iTunes.  There are some limitations and you do need a paid Apple developer account.  This may be why Modenno is asking the question.